# Xcode 4.4: how to disable quick help in code completion window?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.4, xcode4.5

Code completion itself is a good thing, but by 99.9% of time I don't need the new quick help view which was added to it in new Xcode, it only clutters the workspace and (the worst) make the code completion view to be less responsive.

Does anyone know how to turn off quick help view inside code completion view?

I've looked in Xcode's Preferences window and in Xcode's preferences file (com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist), but searching for "completion" or "quickhelp" or just "help" didn't give any results.

Answer (score 1):

Preferences > Text Editing > Uncheck "Suggest completions while typing."

Comment: This will turn auto completion off, but I'm seeking if there is a way to turn off quick help view inside auto completion's view.

Comment: Have you found any solution @zubko?